# Converting 2 vectors into a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays in which I want to convert them into a matrix

```
height = np.array([3,2,4,3,3.5,2,5.5,1])
width = np.array([1.5,1,1.5,1,.5,.5,1,1])
```

I want to convert them into a 2x8 matrix with a method using numpy or pandas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: Do you actually want a matrix, or do you just want a 2D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) if it is your desire to create a 2D array by stacking both of them vertically:

```
height = np.array([3,2,4,3,3.5,2,5.5,1])
width = np.array([1.5,1,1.5,1,.5,.5,1,1])
results = np.vstack((height, width))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.concatenate((height, width), axis=0)`

You'll also need to `reshape` both of them like

```
height = height.reshape(1,-1)
width = width.reshape(1,-1)
result = np.concatenate((height, width), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`asmatrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html) method of Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

height = np.array([3,2,4,3,3.5,2,5.5,1])
width = np.array([1.5,1,1.5,1,.5,.5,1,1])

x = np.asmatrix([height, width])
x
```

The result is

```
matrix([[ 3. ,  2. ,  4. ,  3. ,  3.5,  2. ,  5.5,  1. ],
        [ 1.5,  1. ,  1.5,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using `pandas.DataFrame`

Since you've mentioned `pandas`, you can resolve what you are asking just by defining a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

*Of course*, chose to use `numpy` or `pandas` based on what you have to do next with the obtained matrix.

#### Using vectors as rows

```
import pandas as pd
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([height, width])
```

[image: dataframe rows]

#### Using vectors as columns

```
import pandas as pd
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    "height": np.array([3,2,4,3,3.5,2,5.5,1]),
    "width": np.array([1.5,1,1.5,1,.5,.5,1,1])
})
```

[image: dataframe columns]

Comment: When down-voting one should comment as to why, so that I may fix the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I honestly think this was down voted wrongly. I have flagged it. Cheers!